# Java array using words rather than numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is the chunk of code that I am having issues with:

```
  public void draw() {
        double tax = 0;
        double income = values[0];
        TaxCalculator one = new TaxCalculator();
        tax = one.tax(income);
        double net = 0;
        net = one.net(income);


        for(int i = 0; i<values.length;i++){
            Bar y = new Bar();
            y.makeVisible();

            y.moveHorizontal(20 + i*20);
            y.moveVertical(197 - (int) income);
            y.changeSize(3, (int) income);
            y.changeColour(Colour.BLUE);

            Bar x = new Bar();
            x.makeVisible();

            x.moveHorizontal(20 + i*20);
            x.moveVertical(197 - (int) income - (int) tax);
            x.changeSize(3, (int) tax);
            x.changeColour(Colour.RED);

            }
```

what I am trying to do is create a graph using this Bar class, which is essentially just a editable rectangle.I have 2 numbers per cycle of this loop that should be input, I am calling a array in another class which inputs the first number of that array into what is currently Bar y, and in another chunk of code it is taking that number and performing an operation on it and returning tax which is Bar x, I believe my issue is stemming from the fact that I am rendering the same bar over and over, so I am wondering if there is a way to create multiple objects with different names within a for loop allowing it to progress onto the next value of my array.

If more of my code is needed to resolve this I am happy to post it

Comment: just on first glance it looks like you're drawing the 2nd bar over the 1st bar. You're using the same moveHorizontal argument for both Bars.

Comment: You need to move the income and tax values inside the for loop as well. Now you're setting them before starting the loop, so they'll always be the same (i.e. values[0]). You want `values[i]` as the income.

Comment: if you notice, their vertical position is different, the way it is set up x renders above y so the bottom of x just touches the top of y

Comment: @Kayaman i'm calling both income and tax from different classes and adjusting my code isn't an option for that, as it is part of the specifications of my project

Comment: @BenBowen You do realize that your loop only draws the boxes according to `value[0]`, don't you? Inside your loop the value of income (or tax) never changes. I don't know what "calling both income and tax from different classes" means, but they're both local variables here. You just need to move the code inside the loop.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks, I got it working, though since you didn't write an answer I can't mark this as done so if you want to put something in an answer i'll mark it as done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is using the data that is initialized before the loop, so `income` will always be `values[0]`, and all the bars will only represent the first value.

Moving most of the code (the `TaxCalculator` part can stay outside, since it's most likely reusable) will give you something along the lines of

```
for(int i = 0;i < values.length; i++) {
    double income = values[i];
    double tax = one.tax(income);

    Bar y = new Bar();
    ...
```